# Whats means each part of the SessionId property?

Tags: wcf

I have a per call service, and in my client proxy, I close the proxy when the method has finished. So when I want to call another method, I instantiate a new proxy.

In this second call, I can see that the uuid part of the sessionId is the same in the two calls, but the id part is different.

So if I tried to compared the two sessionId are different.

I would like to know if really the id part is important or not, of if the uuid is the same, really is the same client although the id part is different.

Thanks so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you close proxy then, regardless of whether the session was supported or not, service is destroyed and session is terminated, if any existed.

If you wish to share the same sessionId across many calls you need to make sure both binding and service supports session (either SessionMode.Allowed or SessionMode.Required) and perform calls within the same client.

New client = new session

Comment: Well, my service is session requiered. So if I close the client or if I instantiate a new one, I get a new session, so if my contract set IsInitiating and isTerminating properties of the methods, I have never been able to use any method that is IsInitiating is false. So the unique solution is to instantiate a proxy when the application starts and keep alive the proxy and the connection until the application is closed?

Comment: Whenever you create service object you create session if only session is associated with service. In order to perfom some invocations to service within the same session you need to invoke them for the same service object. Track OperationContext.Current.SessionId in order to make sure session is equivalent. Create proxy call couple methods then close proxy. All calls are supposed to share equivalent SessionId. Then create proxy, call method, close proxy and carry out such a scenario repeatedly. Every time SessionId should be distinct.